# Could not open display using Kubernetes service URL

Tags: x11, display, kubernetes, xvfb

I'm working on launching graphical applications on a k8s cluster.
My configuration is the following :

In a 1st pod, I running a X-server & a VNC Server

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-x-server
      image: <basic_centos_image>
      ports:
        - name: vnc-display
          hostPort: 5901
          containerPort: 5901
          protocol: TCP
        - name: x11-socket
          hostPort: 6001
          containerPort: 6001
          protocol: TCP
```

And the following service :

```
spec:
  ports:
    - name: vnc-display
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5901
      targetPort: 5901
    - name: x11-socket
      protocol: TCP
      port: 6001
      targetPort: 6001
```

I login in the 1st pod and run:

```
Xvfb :1 -listen tcp &
x0vncserver -passwordfile /root/.vnc/passwd -display :1 -rfbport 5901 &
xhost +
```

I can forward the port 6001 on my local machine, launch a VNC client & connect to this server.

In a 2nd pod, I run the following:

```
export DISPLAY=@IP_SERVICE:1
glxgears
```

And I can see the display locally through the VNC Client.

However, if I use the URL of the service within the cluster:

```
export DISPLAY=SERVICE_NAME.NAMESPACE:1
glxgears
```

Then I get the following error :

```
Error: couldn't open display SERVICE_NAME.NAMESPACE:1
```

For precision, in 'basic' pods, the DNS translation works fine in this cluster (for basic HTTP requests for example). I get this error for this specific case of exporting DISPLAY between 2 pods.

Anyone has an idea of why it works if I use the @IP of the service but not it's URL?

Thanks!